# Maven ignores linked repository and transitive dependency is unresolved

Tags: maven

A repository linked in a dependency's pom should be used when handling its dependencies (according to the question [Are Maven repository declarations transitive?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63812808/are-maven-repository-declarations-transitive)). Unfortunately, it doesn't happen in my case.

My project has dependency `org.apache.calcite:calcite-avatica:1.0.0-incubating`. The pom of calcite-avatica requires the dependency `eigenbase:eigenbase-properties:1.1.4` and adds conjar repository in `<repositories>`, as this is the only place where eigenbase-properties 1.1.4 can be found. When I try to build the project, I get an error:

> Could not find artifact eigenbase:eigenbase-properties:pom:1.1.4 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)

Why is `eigenbase-properties` not pulled from conjar repository? Only repository from my project is queried, while the linked repository isn't.

My minimal pom for reference:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>unresolved-dependency</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.calcite/calcite-avatica -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.calcite</groupId>
            <artifactId>calcite-avatica</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0-incubating</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

I'm using JDK 1.8 (as seen in the pom) and Maven 3.6.3 (to exclude the possibility that conjar is blocked as an external http repository, which is the default since 3.8.1; see [How to disable maven blocking external HTTP repositores?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67001968/how-to-disable-maven-blocking-external-http-repositores)).

It also isn't the case that I have some mirrors specified, as was the cause in the question: [maven can't get dependency from transitive repository (sometimes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33396680/maven-cant-get-dependency-from-transitive-repository-sometimes).

Comment: Do you use a `settings.xml`? Does it have mirror definitions?

Comment: No, `settings.xml` is left out default in the minimal example I try to get running, no mirrors.

Comment: Can't reproduce, I see this:Downloading from conjars: http://conjars.org/repo/eigenbase/eigenbase-properties/1.1.4/eigenbase-properties-1.1.4.pom
Downloaded from conjars: http://conjars.org/repo/eigenbase/eigenbase-properties/1.1.4/eigenbase-properties-1.1.4.pom (4.3 kB at 10 kB/s)

Comment: If you run `mvn validate -X` you'll see the locations of the `settings.xml`.

Comment: I tried exactly the same in WSL (ubuntu) and it works there... Same Maven version, jdk version, pom, settings etc. works right away...
It must be Window's fault somehow. I'd say some networking issue like firewall must be the reason, but that would block WSL too.. So no idea what it is, but this could be reproduced only under Windows. @Robert Scholte, what OS did you use?

Comment: Unlikely to be OS related, I use Windows :)

Comment: Ok, I reinstalled the whole java & maven (same distributions), restarted the firewall to defaults, restarted pc, and now it works in Windows too... I have no idea what was wrong before, it will remain a great mystery to me. Still, thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0):

There is no such a "transitive repository" resolution in the documentation of Maven: https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html

Comment: I haven't found anything in Maven docs either, but the accepted answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63812808/are-maven-repository-declarations-transitive indicates there is such thing as "transitive repository".